When I download Jupyter Notebook into HTML as a dark mode user all the colors change and I cannot read certain parts. How do I fix this?
I have recently started using the jupyterthemes dark mode while using Jupyter Notebook. Everything works great while I am coding etc. but when I go to download my notebook as an HTML file, the colors all change and my outputs are unreadable because they blend in with the dark background.  The first picture is what everything looks like when I code, and the second is what I see when I download it.
Currently each time I need to download my notebook I switch back to the default light mode, download, and then switch back to the dark mode, but this is getting really tedious and annoying. I don't mind the all the colors change, I am most bothered by the fact that I cannot read the outputs Any help is appreciated!!
notebook:

HTML:

I have tried looking into the custom.css file to see if I could change some color for the html output, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have been using the dunovank jupyterthemes for reference.
I also tried the following that I saw in a different post but I got the following error.
jupyter nbconvert <notebook_name> --to html --HTMLExporter.theme=dark
error message:

I was expecting the colors not change and to be able to read the outputs. Again, I don't mind that the colors change, but I would like it if I could have a different font color for the output so that it is readable.
